# expected identifier or '(' error when assigning variables to members of a struct array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, strcpy

Here is the header file im using:

```
 typedef struct room room;
 struct room {
 char name[21];      
 int num_doughnuts;  
 int num_milkshakes;
 room* portal[4]; 
 };
```

and my code:

```
struct room* create_room()
{ 
  for(i = 0; i < num_room; i++) 
  {
      room[i] = (struct room*)malloc(sizeof(room));
      printf("input room details\n");
      fgets(input, max_length, stdin);
      sscanf(input, "%s %i %i", room_name, &dnuts, &mshakes);

      strcpy(room[i].name, room_name);  //assign name
      room[i].num_doughnuts = dnuts;  //assign doughnuts
      room[i].num_milkshakes = mshakes;   //assign milkshakes


  }
  return 0;

}
```

And ive declared the room struct in the main function before create_room() is being called

```
    struct room room[num_room];
```

Im supposed to get user input to store a string and two integers for a user defined amount of rooms.

I keep getting an error saying `expected identifier or '('` for these lines:

```
      room[i] = (struct room*)malloc(sizeof(room));
      room[i].num_doughnuts = dnuts;  //assign doughnuts
      room[i].num_milkshakes = mshakes;   //assign milkshakes
```

I'm also getting: unexpected type 'room': expected expression when trying to assign the name:

```
      strcpy(room[i].name, room_name);  //assign name
```

There is something wrong with the way I've declared it but I have no idea what. I've seen a few of these problems and tried a few different types of solutions but I keep getting a similar error.

Can anyone shed some light on this please? I'm really stuck!
Much appreciated!

P.S if it helps all of these rooms have to be stored in a doubly linked list after they've been created, with portal[4] storing pointers to other rooms. I don't know if that has any bearing on my question but extra info never hurt anyone!

Answer (score 1):

You write that array `room` is declared in the main function. Then it is not visible in `create_rooms`. That means the only `room` visible there is the *type* declared by `typedef`, and that's the reason why the compiler complains.

Note that you cannot declare the array `room` *outside* main, as you've already used the global identifier `room` for the type declared by `typedef`. (Why does the declaration within `main` not generate a compile error? If done within main, the local declaration hides the global one, i.e. type `room` is not visible within `main`.)

Solution: Declare the array outside `main` and name it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is this line:

```
typedef struct room room;
```

It's doing funny things every time you try to refer to your struct.  Try just removing it, as you're not using it anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the header file :(

Comment: In that case, change all occurences of `struct room` to just `room` in your C file, as `room` is already an alias for `struct room` (the result being `struct struct room`).

Comment: `typedef struct room room` is common C style and should not generate problems. It is the classical way of avoiding having to write `struct room` every time.

Comment: Not when you use `struct room` within the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing the name "room" in confusing ways

struct room room[num_room]; /* room & room again? */

am surprised it is even compiling, please use different variable names

Also, is num_room a const or #define ?  You are defining an array of rooms and also doing malloc per room in create_room.  Please check that too

In a Quick and dirty way, I made it work, feel free to take hints and ask me if you have specific questions (in comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>


typedef struct room room;
 struct room {
 char name[21];
 int num_doughnuts;
 int num_milkshakes;
 room* portal[4];
 };

int num_room = 2;

struct room* create_rooms()
{

        int i;

   /* Create a pointer to rooms */
   struct room *rooms;
   char input[256], room_name[256];
   int dnuts, mshakes;
   int max_length = 256;


   /* Allocate memory for all rooms */
   rooms = malloc( num_room * sizeof(room) );


  for(i = 0; i < num_room; i++)
  {
      printf("input room details\n");
      fgets(input, max_length, stdin);
      sscanf(input, "%s %i %i", room_name, &dnuts, &mshakes);

      strcpy(rooms[i].name, room_name);  //assign name
      rooms[i].num_doughnuts = dnuts;  //assign doughnuts
      rooms[i].num_milkshakes = mshakes;   //assign milkshakes


  }
  return rooms;

}

main()
{
        struct room *rooms;
        int j;

        rooms = create_rooms();

        for ( j=0; j < num_room; j++ )
        {
                printf( "%s, %d %d\n", rooms[j].name, rooms[j].num_doughnuts, rooms[j].num_milkshakes );
        }

        /* free */
        free (rooms );
}
```

Comment: It's not compiling hence the errors.

num_room is user defined at the very beginning and stays the same throughout the rest of the program.

I cant change room[num_room] to anything else because of the typedef in the header file (if i change it to anything else I get the error:
"unknown type name 'rooms'; did you mean 'room'?"

Can you be more detailed about the malloc issue as well?
Surely I need to malloc each room?

Comment: Is num_rooms a variable or a #define ?

Comment: updated my answer with a quick & dirty program that compiles and works, take hints form it and ask if you have specific questions. Hope it helps

Comment: `struct room room[3];` is valid C, as struct names do not interfere with variable names.